# Google Sheets: Searching a Log of Data but need to find 2 Criteria in One Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 sheets
Sheet1 is where the formula sits and it's searching through Sheet2 which has all the data is imported.

I am trying to find out how many calls an individual has taken each day. The formula is looking for 4 things:

- The person's name
- The date
- If they accepted the call (so is the cell populated, if empty it would not count)
- Looking for the call type of either "inbound" or "callback"

The formula I'm currently using is COUNTIFs:

`=COUNTIFS(Sheet2'!$C$2:$C,$A2,'Sheet2'!$A$2:$A,B2,'Sheet2'!$B$2:$B,"<>",Sheet2'!$D$2:$D,"inbound")`

[image: Sheet2]

I've tried multiple things to say "this" or "that" for the call type but just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!C2:C,A2,Sheet2!A2:A,B2,Sheet2!B2:B,"<>",index(regexmatch(Sheet2!D2:D,"Inbound|Callback")),TRUE)
```

Comment: Dude, this worked! THANK YOU! - Any chance you can explain how INDEX & REGEXMATCH are combined? So frustrating that I looked at REGEXMATCH multiple times but Google's own documentation for it is terrible and I had no clue you could insert multiple 'text' by split it with the " | "

Comment: index is sort of acting as an `arrayformula` here so that regex function can be applied across to the whole range of Sheet2 Column D